# cassandra count (*) query error OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1?

Tags: count, cassandra, timeout, cqlsh

when there is too many rows in cassandra table and I run following query in cqlsh:

```
select count(*) from tableA
```

i get this error:

```
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1
```

how can i resolve this error?

Comment: See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238970/rpc-timeout-in-cqlsh-cassandra).

Comment: count operation is really slow if there is a lot of partitions, increasing timeout will work to a point but you will likely want to switch to using a counter or spark. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29394935/266337

Comment: Since there are people I work with who are forwarding this post to me as something they want done, I feel compelled to mention that increasing the query timeouts in a production cluster is a **terrible, terrible idea.**

Answer (score 4):

For Cassandra 2.0.15+, 2.1.5+, use request_timeout option.

Edit ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc

```
[connection]
request_timeout = 20
```

Refer to this:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlshrc.html#clqshrc__cql-option

Answer (score 0):

chris link is perfect, i had the same problem for counting the total no of records. one way is to use high limit and keep reducing it till the timeout error is resolved.

select count(*) from usertable limit 1000000;

Answer (score -1):

I think you can create cqlshrc file in ~/.cassandra and set client_timeout option in seconds.

~/.cassandra/cqlshrc

```
[connection]
client_timeout = 30
```