# Queries on Beeline and Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, beeline, bigdata

I'm new to using beeline run queries
but why does it take so much time to run a simple query of `SELECT count(*) from table1 [having data of 7,000,000 records]` ?

And when do we use `beeline` instead of `Spark-SQL` and vice-versa?

Thanks

Comment: "Select count(*)" isn't suited for Cassandra queries. Under the hood you are requesting count of data spread across all the Cassandra nodes in the cluster. So its a bad query to Cassandra.

Comment: Your trying to read everything from every range in the cluster, and send it to the coordinator to merge together and count https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394382/operation-time-out-error-in-cqlsh-console-of-cassandra/29394935#29394935

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, i'm beginning to understand now